# Why will my C++ not Compile in VSCode (Terminal Process Fail Exit Code: -1)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

I used the [VS Code C++ Tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) to setup C++.

When I compile my program I get an error in my Terminal:

```
*  Executing task: C/C++: g++.exe build active file 

Starting build...
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g C:\Users\rlifs\Desktop\Home\C++\vscode\setup\main.cpp -o C:\Users\rlifs\Desktop\Home\C++\vscode\setup\main.exe

Build finished with error(s).

 *  The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1). 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

This is my `main.cpp` file:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "VS Code for C++ is working! \n";
    int number{};

    std::cout << "Please enter a number. \n";
    std::cin >> number;

    std::cout << "Your number is: " << number;
    return 0;
}
```

I've been looking for a ton of answers on Stack Overflow but it usually always says something about confirming the Environment Variables. I made sure it was EXACTLY how VSCode website said to do it. I confirmed that I can check the `g++ --version` this is what I get:

```
g++.exe (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.1.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

My Environment Variables goes like this:

`Environment Variables -> User Variables -> PATH -> C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`

Comment: The output you show, that is all you get? You don't get the actual error itself? Have you looked through all tabs and windows of VSCode to see if the error might be reported somewhere else? And have you tried to run the displayed command yourself, manually from a command-line window?

Comment: To me `failed to launch (exit code: -1)` most likely means that `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe` is not the correct path for your compiler. But as stated above, the first thing to try is to take VSCode out of the equation, and try the exact command that VSCode says it cannot execute for yourself.

Comment: Just as a side note: You avoid all that configuration mess if you try, instead of VS code, VS2022 community edition – just install it and work with. If it's for the compiler compiler (I actually consider GCC superior to MSVC) and thus accept going to all this configuration mess (or just want a better IDE), then there are alternatives like Code::Blocks (actually liked it, but didn't offer emacs key bindings when testing those days, so fell out of candidate list for me), NetBeans, or even eclipse (fits my personal needs best still today) – all of I consider superior to both MS products.

Comment: ... that is, apart from setting up and configuring the compiler, of course, as they rely on 3rd party compiler (MinGW), but that has to be done only once.

Comment: Open a Command Prompt and execute `where g++`, then check that the path matches.

Comment: I think we should create a canonical duplicate. "Do not use VSCode, it is broken by design".